# Allow Copy/Paste and change font in an unlocked cell of a locked Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a template in excel where I only want the user to be able to enter information in some of the cells. For that reason I have locked some cells and unlocked some others and I have also protect the corresponding sheet.

The user wants to be able to copy information from other excel sheet to one of the unlocked cells of the template and be able to change the format of the pasted text, being bold and underline options avaliable.

Is there any way to do that without having to unlock the sheet?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are options when you apply protection to the sheet to still allow formatting.

There is no issue copying and pasting into a locked cell as far as I am aware.

There is an option when you apply protection to a worksheet in Excel to allow "Format Cells".  Choose this if you want them to be able to apply formatting to the cell.  Likewise, Format Rows and Format Columns if you want the user to be able top adjust the row height and column width.

Comment: Excellent @SMACKENZIE! This is exactly what I needed and as I have some macros that also unprotect and protect the sheet I have had to add this code to the macros:

Comment: Sheets("name").Visible = True
    Sheets("name").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=True

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped ;-)